# Troubles about insering a POST with a SQL query, post_status

Tags: customization, posts, sql

I 'm using wordpress 3.0.5
I have to use sql for create post, here is my SQL query:

```
$req = $bdd->prepare('INSERT INTO wp_posts (post_title,post_content,post_name,post_date,post_date_gmt,post_modified,post_modified_gmt,post_author,post_status,post_type)
                      VALUES (:post_title, :content, :post_name, now(), now(), now(), now(), 1 ,\'publish\', :post_type)');
```

Everything is fine, my post is created as I want, BUT when I edit my post in admin, for exemple adding a new term, post_status is no more "Publish", but "Scheduled" an my only solution is to `('UPDATE wp_posts SET post_status = \'publish\' WHERE id = :id_post')`

When I creat a post directly in admin, everything is fine even if I edit my post.

I think I missed up the scheduled time !

Can you help me ?
Thank you for your interest.

Answer (score 1):

Why are you using direct SQL query instead of [`wp_insert_post()`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_insert_post)?

I see that you seem to be using non-standard database object. It is hard to guess what goes wrong if you are doing something considerably different from native mechanics.

Comment: Thank for your answer, but I was wondering, what if I can't/don't want to use my script in a wordpress install ?

Comment: @Elium2009 if you take a look at the source of `wp_insert_post()` - it is quite extensive function, not simply stuffing values into database. I don't think it is good/secure idea to fill WP database directly. In my opinion there are better ways to handle this, like [loading WP core in external code](http://codex.wordpress.org/Integrating_WordPress_with_Your_Website) or writing custom import routine as WP plugin.

Comment: "Loading WP core in external code" Love that way ! Thank you !